# What will be the units digit of $7777^{8888}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, decimal-expansion

What will be the units digit of $7777$ raised to the power of $8888$ ?

Can someone do the math with explaining the fact "units digit of $7777$ raised to the power of $8888$"?

Comment: Are you simply asking what the question means? All it's saying is, what's the last digit of $7777^{8888}$. For example, if the answer happened to be 1234567 (it's not), the answer is 7.

Comment: This is not linear algebra, by the way. I've retagged it, which may also be a hint to some as to how to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that any integer $n$ can be written as $10a + b$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers and $b$ is between $0$ and $9$ (inclusive). Written in this way, $b$ is the units digit of $n$. For example $7777 = 10(777) + 7$; here $b = 7$.

Instead of raising a number to such a high power ($8888$), let's start with a smaller power, $2$. If we have written our number $n$ in the form $10a + b$, then we have $$n^2 = (10a + b)^2 = 100a^2 + 20ab + b^2.$$ But this is a positive integer and can be written in the aforementioned way. If $b^2 = 10c + d$ is it's representation, then $10(10a^2 + 2b + c) + d$ is the representation of $n^2$. Note that both $b^2$ and $n^2$ have the same units digit, $d$. We can summarise this by the following:

> The last digit of $n^2$ is the same as the last digit of $(\text{the last digit of}\ n)^2$.

Using our number as an example, we can check this. Note that $$7777^2 = 60481729$$ which has last digit $9$. The last digit of $7777$ is $7$ and $7^2 = 49$, which also has last digit $9$.

Similar reasoning to the above (in particular the [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)) can be used to prove the following generalisation, where $k$ is any positive integer:

> The last digit of $n^k$ is the same as the last digit of $(\text{the last digit of}\ n)^k$.

So for the problem at hand, the above says that the last digit of $7777^{8888}$ is the same as the last digit of $7^{8888}$. The latter is still a huge number, but a little easier to deal with.

As I have explained in a [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/284915/39599), you can figure out what the last digit of $7^{8888}$ is in a fairly easy way. In the linked answer, the question is about the last digit of $2^{2006}$, but the process is the same, just with different numbers.

Comment: Thnx I got you tottaly

Comment: Let guess we have some  numbers with power: $2^{5689}$, $3^{5689}$, $4^{5689}$, $5^{5689}$  ,$6^{5689}$ , $7^{5689}$  , $8^{5689}$, , $9^{5689}$
What I want to know is to evaluate the last digit after expanding the power.

Comment: You can use the method I outline in the linked answer for all of these. Let me know if I have misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 8):

First, you only need the units digit of $7^{8888}$.  The really simple thing is to look for the pattern:  $7^0 \equiv 1, 7^1 \equiv 7, 7^2 \equiv 9, 7^3 \equiv 3, 7^4 \equiv 1 \pmod {10}$ and the pattern repeats.  Since $8888$ is a multiple of $4$, $7777^{8888}$ ends in $1$.

To be a bit more formal, now we have $7777^{8888} \equiv 7^{8888} \equiv (7^4)^{2222}\equiv 1^{2222}=1 \pmod {10}$

Comment: what is mod? does $X=y(mod\ c)$ mean $X=Kc+y$ where $K$ is any integer?

Comment: yes, that is what it means...

Comment: @exploringnet:  that is correct.  Some insist on using $\equiv$ to mean equivalent, so I updated with that.  The remainders on division by any $K$ form a ring, which means you can add, subtract, multiply (and maybe divide) like the integers.  In some rings it is possible, as in $\pmod {10}$ to have $ab=0$ without $a=0$ or $b=0$-take $a=2, b=5$

Comment: What is a ring.( sorry i'm a high school student) in the example you want to say $ab=0(mod\ 10)$? and can we operate these:$a=1(mod\ x)$ and $b=2(mod\ x)$ to get $$a[+,-,\times ,/]b=1[+,-,\times ,/]2 (mod\ x)$$

Comment: @exploringnet:  In abstract algebra we have groups, rings, and fields (and some more).  Groups have one operation, are associative, and have inverses.  Rings are like the integers in the way I said, but can be finite.  You have two operations that act like addition and multiplication, additive inverses, and the distributive law.  Fields are like the reals-you can add, subtract, multiply, and divide (except by 0).  It forms a huge subject.

Answer (score 1):

the units digit of a number is the same as the number mod 10

so we just need to compute $7777^{8888} \pmod {10}$

first $$7777^{8888} \equiv 7^{8888} \pmod {10}$$ and secondly by Eulers totient theorem $$7^{8888} \equiv 7^{0} \equiv 1 \pmod {10}$$ by Eulers totient theorem (since $\varphi(10)=4$ and $4 \mid 8888$)

so there's a quick way to see that the last digit is a 1

Comment: How can we write this $7^{8888} \equiv 7^{0} \equiv 1 \pmod {10}
 
$

Comment: @mysterious, by Eulers totient theorem

Answer (score 0):

$$7777^{1} \equiv 7 \pmod{10}$$

$$7777^{2} \equiv 9 \pmod{10}$$

$$7777^{3} \equiv 3 \pmod{10}$$

$$7777^{4} \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$$

$$7777^{5} \equiv 7 \pmod{10}$$

And the relation continues, in general you see that:

$$7777^{4n + 1} \equiv 7 \pmod{10}$$

And

$$7777^{4n} \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$$

$$\frac{8888}{4} = 2222$$

Hence, $7777^{8888} \equiv 1 \pmod{10}$.