# remainder of the division $2^{1990}/1990$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do we find the remainder of the division $2^{1990}/1990$?
I actually tried it through Fermat's theorem but couldn't arrive at the answer directly.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545759/what-is-the-remainder-when-21990-is-divided-by-1990

Comment: You might want to try using Fermat's Little Theorem along with the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Answer (score -1):

Well, since 1990 is not prime, you might want to look into [Euler's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), which extends Fermat's Little Theorem.

Comment: Euler's Theorem isn't applicable as-is - $2$ and $1990$ are not coprime. There is another theorem you can use to help with this, though.. *hint*