# Remainder from dividing 2^1990 by 1990

Tags: number-theory

Find the remainder when $2^{1990}$ is divided by $1990$. I didn't get answer by Euler's generalization.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545759/what-is-the-remainder-when-21990-is-divided-by-1990

Comment: A quick and painless way: `(2 ^ 1990) \`mod\` 1990` in Haskell says "1024".

Comment: Always use the Chinese remainder theorem to consider only congruences modulo primes (or prime powers). Then use Fermat's little theorem (or Euler's theorem) to simplify the exponent.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see.  199 is prime, so $b^{198x} = 1 \pmod{199}$.  Since the period of $5$ is 4, we see that $b^{1981} = b^1 \pmod{1990} $ for all b.  So it's a matter of finding the remainder of $2^{10} \pmod{1990}$

But since this is $1024$, which is less than $1990$, that is the sought answer.

Comment: Thanks: it should read $b^{1981}$.  Corrected in post.