# What is the last digit of $7^{2015}$?

Tags: exponentiation

What is the last digit of $7^{2015}$?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please indicate what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The last digit of $2^{2006}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284902/the-last-digit-of-22006)

Answer (score 7):

Hint:

Consider $7^1, 7^2, 7^3, \ldots$.

The last digit of this series cycles through 7, 9, 3, 1, 7, and repeats thus.

We can see that it goes through four different last digits.

Now consider 2015 modulo 4.